# How to quickyly find completed PHP website source code in Github?

Tags: php, github

I am new to Github, and want to find some good written PHP website application source code to read. But simply type 'php' as keyword and search on Github is not that effective. Is there any better way to do it?

Also, are PHP frameworks source code good to read and learn?

Comment: Be careful about the code you read. There is lots of bad code out there, particularly PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I think on github there is also a lot of bad written code. I can tell you that maybe working with an CMS might be something for you. While creating Plugins for CMS systems you learn the CMS itself part by part. This way you may understand why things are how they are.

In general, noone simply starts reading Code. You read Code to understand how you interact with an external system.

Comment: thanks, I have coded PHP for several months and I think now it's time to jump into CMS and Frameworks. Any CMS recommend to start? I want to read good code and at the same time creating my own PHP websites. Also any good PHP framework to recommend? How about Codeignitor or Magento?

Comment: I work with TYPO3, its Complicated to get Into, but with Extbase and Fluid its verry MVC (design pattern) based. From the TYPO3 Association there also exists FLOW3 for PHP Applications. I heard often that the Zend Framework is verry important to many Companies. I think Magento is a bit Like TYPO3 but as for all CMS learning to read the Docs and the Code is what you need while Coding Plugins or Extensions for them. About Codeigniter I cant say that much.